# give access to a particular domain in aws llambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

[image]

I have created an API using AWS Lambda functions. I need to give access for the API only to a particular domain.

I have tried out replacing my own domain in the formats like `example.com`, `www.example.com`, `https://www.example.com` in the access control allow origin box. But when I hit the API from outside it is accessible.

Does anyone have some solution for the problem mentioned above?

Only my domain name for eg...www.example.com should have access to the api and other domain names like www.exampl-one.com should not have access

Comment: What do you mean by "give access for the API only to a particular domain"? Are you referring to a web page that is calling the API? Can you provide an example of how this is happening? (Feel free to edit your question to add more details.)

Comment: Thanks John,I am referring to the domain name.Only my domain name should access the api and other domain names should be restricted

Comment: But what do you mean by "Only my domain name should access the api"? Domain names are simply strings that are resolved to an IP address by a DNS server. Can you describe the process you are seeking in more detail?

Comment: Thanks again John, as you mentioned only one ip should access and other ips should be restricted

Answer (score 0):

you can set access-control-allow-origin to the required domain. When webpage hosted under the domain call the API the preflight call will be performed. if referring domain and access-control-allow-origin [cors documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)